# How to get the lanes count of the street of my current position?

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

I use OSMdroid and I want to get the count of lanes of the street i'm driving on.

Normal street have one lane in each direction. Highway have two lanes in each direction. Some streets have more. Is this information stored in OSM and how can I get this informations about my street?

I'm using an `LocationListener` to get the users position.

Comment: Or should I use an other Librrary?

Comment: That will take many steps and access to the raw data of open street maps. You'll have to find the road in that raw data. I have no idea how that works but I imagine it's quite difficult. OSMDroid won't help much. It only shows pre-rendered images.

Comment: @zapl witch library could help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have look at [OverpassAPI](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API), it allows to dig deep and fast in the  OpenStreetMap objects around a specific position.

To perform OverpassAPI requests in your Android context, you can either try [OSMBonusPack OverpassAPIProvider](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/blob/master/OSMBonusPack/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/bonuspack/location/OverpassAPIProvider.java) with the KML flavour, or implement your own request/response parsing.

EDIT

You will need a clear understanding of [OSM lanes tagging conventions](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Lanes). 
This said, I quickly made some trials using OverpassAPI interface integrated in OSMNavigator, just searching with "highway" key: it works.

When on an actual highway, I found "lanes=2" on each side. On usual roads, no "lanes" key defined.

Comment: Thanks! This should work! I'll post my final result when its done!